# console.log() not printing the output

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new to Angular JS and trying to print the username and email on the browser console. I'm either getting 'undefined' or it's printing the string I gave. How can I get the output as Email and Username which user enters? Here's my code:

profile.html

```
<ion-view title="Profile" id="page2">
 <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
  <div ng-controller="profileCtrl"></div>
   <div id="profile-form1" class="list">
  <label class="item item-input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email"  ng-model="Email">
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="Username">
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input" >
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="Password">
  </label>
  <ion-toggle toggle-class="toggle-balanced" id="profile-toggle1" ng-model="tc">Terms &amp; Conditions</ion-toggle>
</div>
<div ng-disabled=" (Email && Username && Password && tc) ? flase : true" ng-click="saveList()" style="border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;" class="button button-balanced  button-block">Login</div>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

controller.js

```
.controller('profileCtrl',  ['$scope', '$stateParams',
  function ($scope, $stateParams) {
    $scope.saveList = function(){
       console.log($scope.Email, $scope.Username);
    }
}])
```

Console output is just undefined undefined.

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if it's related to the issue, but you have a typo: `ng-disabled=" (Email && Username && Password && tc) ? flase : true"` flase is not a valid boolean value.

Comment: `<div ng-controller="profileCtrl"></div>` because that button _or anything else_ is not in your controller

Comment: @Shilly if I don't include 'false', login button is activated even if none of the fields are filled. I guess there's no other way to disable the login button when fields are empty.

Comment: I meant that you misspelled 'false' as 'flase', something JS won't be able to convert to the correct boolean value false.

Comment: Ahhh... I got you. Thanks for correcting the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't close the div : `<div ng-controller="profileCtrl"></div>`

and don't forget to close the `div` tag  :

```
 <ion-view title="Profile" id="page2">
 <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
     <div ng-controller="profileCtrl"> <!-- open it here -->
       <div id="profile-form1" class="list">
         <label class="item item-input">
           <input type="text" placeholder="Email"  ng-model="Email">
         </label>
         <label class="item item-input">
           <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="Username">
         </label>
         <label class="item item-input" >
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="Password">
         </label>
        <ion-toggle toggle-class="toggle-balanced" id="profile-toggle1" ng-model="tc">Terms &amp; Conditions</ion-toggle>
      </div>
      <div ng-disabled=" (Email && Username && Password && tc) ? flase : true" ng-click="saveList()" style="border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;" class="button button-balanced  button-block">Login</div>
    </div> <!-- close it here -->
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```